# vhost permission denied to upload file

Tags: php, apache

I create a vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.carrosibague.gov.co
        ServerAlias carrosibague.gov.co
        DocumentRoot /var/www/portal/public_html

<Directory "/var/www/portal/public_html">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride None
 #Order allow,deny
 #Allow from all
 Require all granted
 php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/portal/public_html:.:/php:/tmp"
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

but when a try to upload a file

**Warning:**

> move_uploaded_file(../../../archivos/imagenes/slides/noticias/20161116-193.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/portal/public_html/portal/admin/modulos/portal/imagenes/slide_principal.php
>   on line 312

the directory permissions are 755 with owner apache:apache

Comment: Where is your question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried 775 ?

Comment: have you tried 777 and also your apache would need to have write/execute access

Comment: Yes, i tried with 775 and 777 permissions, but don´t work

Comment: the question is why i cant upload files, the apache version is 2.4.6 and php 5.4.16

Comment: Well, I ran chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t user and it worked.